# Problem opening camera in onTopResumedActivityChanged

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-10.0

I have an Android app that uses the Camera. Until now, I was opening the camera in my activity's `onResume` callback, and releasing it in `onPause`. This worked fine before Android 10.

Starting from Android 10, there may be more than one activity in RESUMED state so instead I am trying to open/release the camera in the new `onTopResumedActivityChanged` callback. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onTopResumedActivityChanged(boolean)) says:

> This callback should be used instead of onResume() as an indication that the activity can try to open exclusive-access devices like camera.

I am testing this on a split-screen setup, with another camera app running. Sometimes when I tap my app it will successfully open the camera; sometimes it will fail with a runtime exception as follows:

```
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8, EX_SERVICE_SPECIFIC): '7: connectHelper:1500: Higher-priority client using camera, ID "0" currently unavailable'
E/CameraPreview: Cannot open camera
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:630)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:455)
        [...]
```

Why is this happening? Theoretically if `onTopResumedActivityChanged` is called with `isTopResumedActivity` set to true, my activity is already the top resumed activity, and should be the highest priority client for the camera.

Comment: Can it be a race case? As in, your activity is getting the focus but the camera is not yet ready to be used and you are instantly trying to use it? Just to check it, maybe put a delay of like, 1 second in your function and see if that problem still occurs

Comment: I think the other app failed to release the camera. That might be the issue at first sight

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps, but try this:

As the docs say:

> Called when activity gets or loses the top resumed position in the
> system. Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.Q multiple activities can be
> resumed at the same time in multi-window and multi-display modes. This
> callback should be used instead of onResume() as an indication that
> the activity can try to open exclusive-access devices like camera. It
> will always be delivered after the activity was resumed and before it
> is paused. In some cases it might be skipped and activity can go
> straight from onResume() to onPause() without receiving the top
> resumed state.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onTopResumedActivityChanged(boolean)

So, it says it won't always be called, yet when it is called, it's before onResume.

You can have a flag to indicate if you've handled on both `onTopResumedActivityChanged` and `onResume` (and on both, also handle this event if it wasn't handled), and reset it on `onPause`.

Comment: Ehm I don't quite understand what we are expected to do here. First the documentation specifically says we should use onTopResumedActivityChanged instead of onResume. Then it says sometimes it will be skipped. How are we expected to handle this??

Comment: *> So, it says it won't always be called, yet when it is called, it's before onResume.* 

Doesn't it actually say the opposite? ("it will be always delivered **after** the activity was resumed")

Comment: Anyway I'm not sure how this explains the behaviour described in the question. In my case I am trying to open the camer from the onTopResumedActivityChanged callback and sometimes that fails, and the question is "why?" -- since the activity should already be the top resumed activity when this callback is called .

Comment: I don't know if this will help you. As for the alleged contradiction, it says it will always have certain behavior, but it doesn't say that it will always be called. It's like this rule : "if X and Y occurred, it means Y happened before". Does it mean that X always occur together with Y ? No, because Y can occur alone.

Comment: @Grodriguez If there is a crash that you can reproduce, you can also write about it on the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923&template=841312

Comment: The contradiction I am referring to is in the fact that they say that onTopResumeActivityChanged "should used instead of onResume" in my specific use case (open the camera) which does not seem to be feasible if sometimes onTopResumeActivityChanged is not even called.

Comment: @Grodriguez OK so no idea. If you can reproduce the issue, I suggest to report about it. Maybe they will also tell you what's wrong in what you are doing, or agree it's a bug and fix it